# Recording and listening wife moans during sex

Tags: sex, love, wife, husband, sexuality

For those men who live abroad away from their wives for their jobs, can they record their wife's moans during sex with him, and listen to it when he is away from her, is it allowed in islam as he is listening to his own wife's moan rather than any non mahram women's. Is it allowed?

Comment: For what should this be good for? I rather see issues -> committing something sinful.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit controversial. In my own opinion, there's no such thing as "Safe" in technology. our hijab can be exposed at any moment (e.g hacker, human error, etc.) so it's best for the husband to take fasting instead rather than forcing his own libido (we can hold it in 10 years without it consecutively before we married why we can't now?). many of us man able to resist such temptation for quite a long time. there's no real urgency here what so ever. just wait until he comes home (which he should)